# Possible issue with Publish subscribe Channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have an application that monitors FTP folder for a specific csv file `foo.csv`, once the file is located it pulls it to my local and generate a new output format bar.csv, the application then will send the new file `finalBEY.csv` back to the FTP folder and erase it from local.

Now that I have introduced a process using `publishSubscribeChannel` where it transforms the file to a message then uses `jobLaunchingGateway` that will read `finalBEY.csv` using batch and print it to the consol, it is not working since the `finalBEY.csv` is being deleted from the local forlder after sending it back to FTP, I'm using `.channel("nullChannel")` on the `jobLaunchingGateway` within the first `subscribe` which suppose to hold it until having a reply from the batch and then moves to the next `subscribe` which will send it to the ftp and remove it from local, but seems it is not the case where it is removing it from local and thus the batch is not finding `finalBEY.csv` and throws an error that I'm pasting below with the code.

If I remove the advice from the second `subscribe` it works fine as this will not delete it from local anymore.

Can you please assist on this matter?

```
public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                        .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                                .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv"))
                                .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
                .enrichHeaders(h ->h.headerExpression("file_originalFile", "new java.io.File('"+ myBranch.getBranchCode() +"/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv')",true))
                .transform(p -> {
                    LOG.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());
                    return p;
                })

                .log()
                .transform(m -> {
                            this.defaultSessionFactoryLocator.addSessionFactory(myBranch.getBranchCode(),createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch));
                            LOG.info("Adding factory to delegation");
                            return m;
                })
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s ->
                        s.subscribe(f ->f.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())
                                        .handle(jobLaunchingGateway()).channel("nullChannel"))
                        .subscribe(h -> h.handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                                         .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                                         .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                                         .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))))

                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest(){
        FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
        fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("file_path");
        fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(orderJob);
        return fileMessageToJobRequest;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
        JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);

        return jobLaunchingGateway;
    }

    /**
    * Creating the advice for routing the payload of the outbound message on different expressions (success, failure)
    * @return Advice
    */

    @Bean
    public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
        advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");
        //advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile'].renameTo(new java.io.File(payload.absolutePath + '.success.to.send'))");
        //advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }
```

Here is the error and as you can see the first lines show that it is transferred to FTP and then initiated the batch job while in the subscribe should do the batch first...

```
 INFO 10452 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully renamed from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing to /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file [C:\Java Programs\spring4ftpappftp\BEY\finalBEY.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 123 common frames omitted
```

Debugging code:

```
2019-07-15 10:43:02.838  INFO 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred to: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing
2019-07-15 10:43:02.845  INFO 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully renamed from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing to /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv
2019-07-15 10:43:02.845 DEBUG 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
2019-07-15 10:43:02.848 DEBUG 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'success.input'
2019-07-15 10:43:02.849 DEBUG 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'success.input', message: AdviceMessage [payload=true was successful, headers={id=eca55e1d-918e-3334-afce-66f8ab650748, timestamp=1563176582848}, inputMessage=GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, id=a2f029b0-2609-1a11-67ef-4f56c7dd0752, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1563176582787}]]
2019-07-15 10:43:02.849 DEBUG 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : success.org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0 received message: AdviceMessage [payload=true was successful, headers={id=eca55e1d-918e-3334-afce-66f8ab650748, timestamp=1563176582848}, 

inputMessage=GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, id=a2f029b0-2609-1a11-67ef-4f56c7dd0752, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1563176582787}]]

    2019-07-15 10:43:02.951 DEBUG 4280 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.b.i.launch.JobLaunchingGateway       : jobLaunchingGateway received message: GenericMessage [payload=JobLaunchRequest: orderJob, parameters={file_path=C:\Java Programs\spring4ftpappftp\BEY\finalBEY.csv, dummy=1563176582946}, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, id=c98ad6cb-cced-c911-1b93-9d054baeb9d0, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1563176582951}]

2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.FTPOutp' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1o.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the '1o.subFlow#1.channel#0' channel
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.1o.subFlow#1.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1o.subFlow#1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'FTPOutp' channel
2019-07-16 08:35:29.442  INFO 10208 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.FTPOutp' has 2 subscriber(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `SyncTaskExecutor` the batch job should run on the calling thread and then followed by the FTP adapter.

Use DEBUG logging and follow the message flow to see why that's not happening.

Comment: Thanks Gary, after debugging it looks like it is doing the `Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch)` and thus `expressionAdvice()` which is deleting the file from the local folder and thus not existing for the batch processing, I'm not able to know why it is doing that but I'm assuming that when I'm entering the FTP server using the front end form and passing it to this method , it is launching `Ftp.outboundAdapter` first, I know not logic but could not find any other reason, I added the debugging part for that maybe you can see something different..thanks@Gary Russel

Comment: Isn't that a fact that ` jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)` is an *async* operation? Can you show DEBUG logs when message reaches that `publishSubscribeChannel()` to be sure in what order its subscribers are called. You can add an `id()` to that channel for better traceability in logs.

Comment: It should be sync because he's using a `SyncTaskExecutor`.

Comment: It's strange - you can see the same poller thread runs both. They should run in order because the subscriptions are stored in a `LinkedHashMap`. The actual subscribers are bridges - maybe the spec needs to explicitly set the `order` properties on the bridges?

Comment: I added new DEBUG code when it enters the `publishSubscribeChannel()` , seems it is not entering the first `subscribe` it is jumping to the second one, I added IDs on both channels and I can only find the ID of the second one only, not sure if this highlights anything to get it fixed..@Gary Russell

Comment: If you can post a sample application that exhibits this behavior, we can take a look.

Comment: I have uploaded a project sample to this link (github.com/EliasKhattar/SpringBatchIntegration) you can run it and go to local hosthost:8081 and it will trigger the flows and generate the error, the file is in folder BEY and it should be a valid FTP server to get the error so if you provide an invalid server it will go through with no error and reads the file with batch...thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: Unfortunately, that is much too big for me to get my arms around with the limited time that I have; can you not create a small example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I simplified it as much as possible and uploaded new one  https://github.com/EliasKhattar/SpringBatchIntegration ], you do not need FTP server anymore, you can just run it and go to `localhost:8081` and will trigger the error in question, also the whole config file is in folder configuration with name `FTPIntegration` along with other Batch config files, thanks Gary, let me know if this is still too big@Gary Russell

Comment: Hi Gary - did you have the chance to look into this again? Thank you @Gary Russell

Comment: Sorry, I was out Friday and have been catching up all day. I don't have postgres installed; can you not reproduce it with a simple IntgrationFlow with two subscribers on a pub/sub?

Comment: Which version are you using? A [problem like this was fixed in Spring Integration 5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/3c047c5076450c8568cf0cab533754460573f454) by adding a bridge to the start of each subflow. In that version, the DSL was integrated into the core project. This change was NOT applied to the old standalone java-dsl project used with Spring Integration 4.3.x.

Comment: Never mind - I see you are using Boot 2.0.3 and Spring Integration 5.0.6; so this is weird.

Comment: Not a problem, yes this looks weird after I checked the fix above, I uploaded a new copy that does not use Postgres rather it uses embedded H2 so just go to localhost:8081 and the issue will show, if I comment `advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");` in `expressionAdvice()` the batch will read the file, so basically it is deleting it on the second subscribe before doing the first subscribe ...thanks again for looking into this @Gary Russell

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance (and thanks for the sample); the problem is dynamic integration flows are started in reverse order (so we don't start receiving messages before the flow is completely built). This has the side effect of subscribing to pub/sub channels backwards. We need to think about how to resolve this but, in the meantime, simply reverse the two subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you Gary for the help on this issue, definitely I reversed the subscriptions and it is working smoothly, I hope from my case I highlighted on a possible enhancement on dynamic flows with pub/sub, if I want to be informed when this is going to be fixed and released, should I be following any news somewhere?Thank you again @Gary Russell

Comment: You can follow (subscribe to) [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3003).